# How to safely deserialize MessagePack messages without throwing exceptions?

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, msgpack

It's my DTO:

```
public class InvocationMessage
{
    public string MethodName { get; set; }
    public object?[]? Args { get; set; }
}
```

And initially I serialized it using `MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(Msg, ContractlessStandardResolver.Options);`

Then while deserializing I wanted to convert `object` from `Args` to concrete types. It occured to be impossible without custom formatters. So I wrote one:

```
public InvocationMessage Deserialize(ref MessagePackReader reader, MessagePackSerializerOptions options)
{
    var result = new InvocationMessage
    {
        MethodName = reader.ReadString()
    };

    // Hardcoded for testing purpose
    var argTypes = new Type[] { typeof(SomeType) };
    if (reader.TryReadArrayHeader(out int count))
    {
        result.Args = new object?[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < argTypes.Length; i++)
        {
            result.Args[i] = MessagePackSerializer.Deserialize(argTypes[i], ref reader,
                ContractlessStandardResolver.Options.WithSecurity(MessagePackSecurity.UntrustedData));
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public void Serialize(ref MessagePackWriter writer, InvocationMessage value, MessagePackSerializerOptions options)
{
    var methodName = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value.MethodName);

    writer.WriteString(methodName);

    if (value.Args is not null && value.Args.Length > 0)
    {
        writer.WriteArrayHeader(value.Args.Length);

        foreach (var arg in value.Args)
        {
            MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(ref writer, arg, ContractlessStandardResolver.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunelly, the exception is always thrown when I try to deserialize e.g. something like this:

```
var msg = new InvocationMessage
{
    MethodName = "sometestname",
    Args = new object?[]
        {
            new 
            {
                Test = 3
            },
            new
            {
                ReceiverId = "12ds",
                Content = "s",
            },
            new 
            {
                Test2 = 5
            },
        }
};
```

It's because I want to deserialize some unknown type to my `SomeType`, or because my `SomeType` wants `string` for property `ReceiverId` and gets `int`. There are many cases where it throws.

But I need to avoid throws because it's big performance issue for my app. There is no something like `TryDeserialize` method, so I don't have any idea what can I do.

Comment: What does your `SomeType` class look like?

Comment: Generally, while deserializing I get types of all 'result.Args' in order. I dont event know what are these types . This 'SomeType' is for example and how it looks doesnt matter because as I said on real code I also dont know how the types look, they are provided using reflection from methods I dont know which some dev declares.

Comment: If you don't know what types to expect in `Args` how do you want to deserialize them into concrete types?
If you only want the `MessagePackSerializer` to deserialize all contents from `Args` in order they appeared, you might use `MessagePackObject` and `Key` attributes (for more information see https://github.com/MessagePack-CSharp/MessagePack-CSharp#object-serialization).

Sorry, without further information on the purpose of your application, what exception gets thrown, and what contents you receive in `Args`, one might not fully understand your problem.

Comment: Its something like SignalR hub. The man who use it defines hub methods and the SignalR doesn't know what arguments will be used in these methods. But it must deserialize these arguments which are stored in `object?[]`. The SignalR only know what type should be at `i` position of `Args`. But the sent object can be malformed (eg by attacke) and then exception will be thrown. I have analogical case and I must avoid exceptions.

Comment: @Szyszka947 Have you tried changing the serialization to typeless? https://github.com/MessagePack-CSharp/MessagePack-CSharp#typeless

Comment: I think it wont work because I dont share the same models in TS and C#. I mean that serialized class names can differ etc.

Comment: @Szyszka947 Then you need to deserialize into a dynamic model https://github.com/MessagePack-CSharp/MessagePack-CSharp/blob/master/doc/ExpandoObject.md

Comment: Later I will have problems with casting the dynamic to my object. Probably I will need to use reflection :/ Seems I should stick with JSON.

Comment: @Szyszka947 How do you solve your problem using JSON?

Comment: After validating the JSON structure no exception will be thrown during serialization. Just I need to use nullable properties.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to edit your deserialization code to use a custom formatter that handles unknown types or type mismatches, so first of all define a custom formatter for your `InvocationMessage`

```
public class InvocationMessageFormatter : IMessagePackFormatter<InvocationMessage>
{
    public InvocationMessage Deserialize(ref MessagePackReader reader, MessagePackSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var result = new InvocationMessage
        {
            MethodName = reader.ReadString()
        };

        if (reader.TryReadArrayHeader(out int count))
        {
            result.Args = new object?[count];

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                result.Args[i] = DeserializeObject(ref reader, options);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void Serialize(ref MessagePackWriter writer, InvocationMessage value, MessagePackSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteString(value.MethodName);

        if (value.Args is not null && value.Args.Length > 0)
        {
            writer.WriteArrayHeader(value.Args.Length);

            foreach (var arg in value.Args)
            {
                SerializeObject(ref writer, arg, options);
            }
        }
    }

    private object? DeserializeObject(ref MessagePackReader reader, MessagePackSerializerOptions options)
    {
        /* you can return null or a default value for unknown types,
         or convert the object to the expected type if possible.
         I'll simply return null for unknown types */
        return null;
    }

    private void SerializeObject(ref MessagePackWriter writer, object? value, MessagePackSerializerOptions options)
    {
        //you can throw an exception or convert the object to a compatible type,for example, I'll do nothing when serializing unknown types
    }
}
```

now you can easily register the custom formatter in your serialization/deserialization code

```
var options = MessagePackSerializerOptions.Standard.WithResolver(ContractlessStandardResolver.Options);
options = options.WithFormatter<InvocationMessage>(new InvocationMessageFormatter());

//serialize
var serializedBytes = MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(msg, options);

//deserialize
var deserializedMsg = MessagePackSerializer.Deserialize<InvocationMessage>(serializedBytes, options);
```

Comment: But how can I ensure that some bytes represents valid type? I know, I can catch exception, but I must avoid them

Comment: many ways, for example before deserializing, you can perform some basic checks on the serialized data to ensure it is valid. For example, you can check if the byte array is not null or empty, or if it has a minimum length or when deserializing, read the type identifier from the bytes and check if it matches the expected type. If they don't match, you can handle the error accordingly and so on!

Comment: But it wont be efficient because I probably would need to use reflection in my case :/ It kills benefits of MessagePack (performance).